# SoundCloud Custom Player

Tags: widget, soundcloud, social-media-like

I am trying to build a custom player like that one that is given in the example section: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/tree/master/examples (minimal)

The big problem for me is to include a like button and I was wondering if this is easily possible. I do know, that I could include the JavaScript SDK and after the authentication process it would be able to use a like button.

I don't want the user to log in because it would be much better if the like process would be like the one in the official SoundCloud player widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With official SoundCloud widget you too need to login in order to “like” a sound.

Comment: Thank you for your help, you are right. I have to use a custom player because the official widget is too slow when you have to load 20 of them. Do you maybe know a way to speed up the loading, so it becomes as fast like the players on soundcloud.com?

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much to do on your side to speed up widgets. You could maybe only load the widgets on certain user interaction, for example when user scrolls and widget container gets into viewport. Otherwise, in order to be able to like tracks you could use JavaScript SDK with playback capabilities and build the UI that controls the playback and other actions yourself